# Cython int ** and int * types

Tags: python, c, cython

I am trying to wrap some C code with Cython, but I am running into a error that I don't understand, and despite a lot of searching I cannot seem to find anything on it. Here is my c code

```
void cssor(double *U, int m, int n, double omega, double tol, int maxiters, int *info){
double maxerr, temp, lcf, rcf;
int i, j, k;
lcf = 1.0 - omega;
rcf = 0.25 * omega;
for (k =0; k < maxiters ; k ++){
    maxerr = 0.0;
    for (j =1; j < n-1; j++) {
        for (i =1; i < m-1; i++) {
            temp = U[i*n+ j];
            U[i*n+j] = lcf * U[i*n+j] + rcf * (U[i*n+j-1] + U [i*n+j+1] + U [(i-1)*n + j] + U [(i+1)*n+j]);
            maxerr = fmax(fabs(U[i*n+j] - temp), maxerr);
        }
    }
    if(maxerr < tol){break;}
}
if (maxerr < tol) {*info =0;}
else{*info =1;}
```

}

My .pyx file is

```
    cdef extern from "cssor.h":
        void cssor(double *U, int m, int n, double omega, double tol, int maxiters, int *info)

    cpdef cyssor(double[:, ::1] U, double omega, double tol, int maxiters, int *info):
        cdef int n, m
        m = U.shape[0]
        n = U.shape[1]
        cssor(&U[0, 0], m, n, omega, tol, maxiters, &info)
```

However, when I try to run the associated setup file I get an error referring to maxiters in the last line of the code that says:

Cannot assign type 'int **' to type 'int *'

Can you tell me how to fix this?

Roy Roth

Comment: Change `&info` to `info`.

Comment: To answer this question requires going through a lot more code than is needed to reproduce the problem. Although you got your answer this time, you're likely to get better responses in future if you minimize your examples.

Answer (score 4):

The problem comes from here:

```
cpdef cyssor(double[:, ::1] U, double omega, double tol, int maxiters, int *info):
    cdef int n, m
    m = U.shape[0]
    n = U.shape[1]
    cssor(&U[0, 0], m, n, omega, tol, maxiters, &info)
```

You declare `info` as type `int*`. But you then pass it into the `cssor` function as a reference to an `int*`, making it an `int**`.

The correct code is:

```
cssor(&U[0, 0], m, n, omega, tol, maxiters, info)
```